# Scala, circe and decoding

Tags: json, scala, circe

In scala and circe, given Json objects as follows

```
import io.circe._ 
import io.circe.syntax._ 

val x: Json = Json.fromString("foo")
val y: Json = List(1, 2, 3).asJson
```

I would like to divise a way to detect if the content of `x` is a really a String literal (which is the case, "foo") while `y` is not (its a list). Any hints ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def isString(json: io.circe.Json): Boolean = json.isString
```

Or just: `x.isString`, `y.isString`.